# Opendns setup failed. How to fix it?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, configuration, dns

I have problems trying to configure OpenDNS. I have contacted OpenDNS support but they did not answer. I cannot access websites like Twitter and Facebook. 
[image: another example]
[image: Twitter cannot be accessed.]

I tried welcome.opendns.com (did not work, shows not using OpenDNS.
[image: OpenDNS not using.]

Using nslookup:

```
 $ nslookup -type=txt which.opendns.com. 208.67.222.222
Server:     208.67.222.222
Address:    208.67.222.222#53

Non-authoritative answer:
which.opendns.com   text = "7.sin"

Authoritative answers can be found from:

$ nslookup -type=txt debug.opendns.com.
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
debug.opendns.com   text = "server 3.sin"
debug.opendns.com   text = "flags 20 0 2f6 0"
debug.opendns.com   text = "id 13521181"
debug.opendns.com   text = "source 222.164.129.44:62574"

Authoritative answers can be found from:

$ nslookup www.exampleadultsite.com.
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.exampleadultsite.com
Address: 67.215.92.210
```

Comment: What are the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/228007167-Linux-Mint-Cinnamon

Answer (score 0):

Try running `dns-fix`. This worked for me. Linux Mint 14 has OpenDNS built in so I think this just sets up the OpenDNS stuff for you.